# bs-stepper not working in my angular code

Tags: angular, typescript, uistepper

I'm using bs-stepper module in my angular code its not working as expected, its throwing some errors
please look at my code here

```
export class FileUploadProcessComponent implements OnInit {
     import Stepper from 'bs-stepper';

// @ViewChild("stepperProcess") stepperProcess : Element | null
     NgOnInit(): void {
         document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
              var stepper = new Stepper(<Element>  document.querySelector('.bs-stepper'))
         })
    }
}
```

Html code is

```
<div id="stepper1" class="bs-stepper" #stepperProcess>
                <div class="bs-stepper-header">
                  <div class="step" data-target="#test-l-1">
                    <button class="step-trigger">
                      <span class="bs-stepper-circle">1</span>
                      <span class="bs-stepper-label">Email</span>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="line"></div>
                  <div class="step" data-target="#test-l-2">
                    <button class="step-trigger">
                      <span class="bs-stepper-circle">2</span>
                      <span class="bs-stepper-label">Password</span>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="line"></div>
                  <div class="step" data-target="#test-l-3">
                    <button class="step-trigger">
                      <span class="bs-stepper-circle">3</span>
                      <span class="bs-stepper-label">Validate</span>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bs-stepper-content">
                  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
                    <div id="test-l-1" class="content">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email" />
                      </div>
                      <button (click)="next()" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="test-l-2" class="content">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password" />
                      </div>
                      <button (click)="next()" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="test-l-3" class="content text-center">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-5">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
```

And the errors are

> ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[Stepper -> Stepper
> -> Stepper]:    NullInjectorError: No provider for Stepper!
> at NullInjector.get (core.mjs:6364:27)
> at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:6791:33)
> at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:6791:33)
> at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:6791:33)
> at ChainedInjector.get (core.mjs:13868:36)
> at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (core.mjs:3286:39)
> at getOrCreateInjectable (core.mjs:3331:12)
> at Module.ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.mjs:10881:12)
> at NodeInjectorFactory.FileUploadProcessComponent_Factory [as factory] (file-upload-process.component.ts:17:40)
> at getNodeInjectable (core.mjs:3516:44)

Comment: can you make a stackblitz example?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/bs-stepper-angular Check this link, in this stackblitz they using angular 8 but in my app im using angular 14

Answer (score 1):

`NgOnInit()` should be `ngOnInit()`. Working example here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/bs-stepper-angular

Comment: same stackblitz im trying, but im using angular 14. its not working

Comment: I think something issue with mapping element, i don't know the issue exactly